# Compiling multiple source directories with g++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation, g++

My c++ project has the following structure

```
src
|
|source1.cpp
|source2.cpp
|
|<srcfolder1>
|__ source11.cpp
|__ source12.cpp
|
|<srcfolder2>
|__ source21.cpp
|__ source22.cpp
```

As can be seen there are multiple folders with multiple source files.
What command do i give g++ to compile all the source file into a single .o file?

Comment: Erm, give it all the source files?

Comment: there are about a 100 source files. too many to list them one by one on the command line prompt

Comment: I think the common way in complex projects is to have Makefiles in each sub-folder and to invoke them from the parent folders. BTW, why aren't you using an IDE anyway?

Comment: I was actually using visual studio on windows to do the compilation. Now i have to compile these for linux and i am lost on the command line

Comment: I recommend `Qt Creator` as an alternative that works on Linux, Mac and windows alike :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have many source files you should really consider writing a Makefile:
http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

You can for example use a syntax similar to this to compile multiple files (in the Makefile):

```
%.o : $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.cpp
  $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Rolle, my makefile knowledge is now only what i read in that article you linked to ;) Could you please explain the command you described. what does the % sign stand for?

Comment: There must be more tutorials online that explains it better than what i can explain here. Basically the above reads: for each source file in SRC_FOLDER (defined elsewhere), compile using the command line argument defined in CXX, with the flags -c -o, naming them to the same name as the cpp file but with the ending .o. See also my edit above

Answer (score 2):

You could also use build systems that would generate the actual makefile for you. This becomes important as you try to expand your project and maintaining a *good* makefile might become a daunting task. I suggest that you spend some time to learn one. Examples are `Scons`, GNU `autotools`, `qmake`, and `Cmake`, among others. I highlly reccomond the use of `qmake` or `Cmake` as they are both cross-platform and easy to learn.

Another option that you have is to simply use an IDE! The best `c++` IDE on Linux that I know of, and is cross-platform, is `Qt Creator`. Under the hood it supports both `qmake` and `Cmake` projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to working with Visual Studio and you have to compile your files under linux, there is no need to start doing everything on the command line ;)

Like GradGuy pointed out, **QtCreator** is a great IDE and I also use it for my non-windows builds. However, if you don't do any GUI stuff, you might want to use it with together with `cmake` as Qt is mostly about GUIs.

`cmake` is a generator for the solution files (like VS' .sln files) that is independent of what IDE or you operating system you are running. It is a bottom-up approach where you need very little to just get going.

Here are some steps to get you started

- install qtcreator and cmake
- write a file telling `cmake` where your source files are and where to find them.
- create a file `CMakeLists.txt` in the folder above `src` and write inside the following:

  ```
  project( myProject )

  # set your include directories (if you have any)
  include_directories( include )

  # tell cmake what what are your source files
  set( MY_CPP_FILES 
      src/source1.cpp
      src/source2.cpp
      src/srcfolder1/source11.cpp
      src/srcfolder1/source12.cpp
      src/srcfolder2/source21.cpp
      src/srcfolder2/source22.cpp )

  # if you are creating an executable then do so like this
  # note that ${MY_CPP_FILES} will replace it with its content
  add_executable( myExec ${MY_CPP_FILES} )

  # if you instead want a library, do it like so
  add_library( myStaticLib STATIC ${MY_CPP_FILES} ) # create a static library
  add_library( mySharedLib SHARED ${MY_CPP_FILES} ) # create a shared library
  ```
- now start QtCreator and choose `File -> Open File or Project` and select `CMakeLists.txt`  on your drive
- now you will be asked to choose a path where the results will be stored (as well as all intermediate files)
- hit `Run CMake`
- and finally choose `Build -> Build All`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the most direct answer is something like:

```
g++ $(find src -name '*.cpp')
```

That said, having so many translation units, having a Makefile helps to dramatically reduce build times as you edit your source files and build to test.