# Compiling C++ Files

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

Trying to compile .cpp files into .o files to then pack them into a .exe, i've worked out the process, however i'm unsure how this is going to work when there is 100s of files, here is my current compile batch file:

```
del *.exe
cls
g++ -c .\lib\func\func.cpp
g++ -c .\main.cpp
g++ -o App.exe *.o 
del *.o
App.exe
```

This works fine, however I need a line for each .cpp file is there a way I get it to compile all .cpp files? guessing `g++ -c *.cpp` would work but then I couldn't have any files in a sub folder.

Looked through online resources and through the help on g++, however this usually refers to compiling two files rather than a larger amount.

Was expecting a method like `g++ -c *.cpp` however as mentioned this only works if all the files are in one directory.

Comment: This should solve your problem: [How can you compile all cpp files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662375/how-can-you-compile-all-cpp-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Or [Compiling multiple source directories with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851153/compiling-multiple-source-directories-with-g)

Comment: "how this is going to work when there is 100s of files" - you should get familiar with build tools like cmake, meson, scons, and so on...